# Create constraints, nodes and relationships within a cypher query

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher

I am new to graph database. My project is accessing neo4j 3.2.0 via Rstudio.

Snapshot of my data input:

> head(cleandata)

```
  TimeSeconds ipLayerProtocol firstSeenSrcIp firstSeenSrcPort firstSeenDestIp firstSeenDestPort
1  1365582756              17     172.20.2.3            29961 239.255.255.250              1900
2  1365582756              17    172.20.2.18            29986 239.255.255.250              1900
3  1365582756              17    172.20.2.17            29985 239.255.255.250              1900
```

My desired output:

[Desired graph output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7kQXV.png)

> What I would like to do:
>   Like to commit the query containing multiple cypher statements at one go in batches of 5000.

Below is the code:

```
query = "
  CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (ipcluster:IPCluster) ASSERT ipcluster.ip IS UNIQUE 
  CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (origin:IPNode) ASSERT origin.ipport IS UNIQUE 
  CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (dest:IPNode) ASSERT dest.ipport IS UNIQUE

  MERGE (ipcluster:IPCluster {ip: {SrcIP} })
  CREATE (flow:Flow {timestamp: {TimeSeconds},protocol:{TransportProto} })
  SET flow.timestamp = TOINT({TimeSeconds})

  MERGE (origin:IPNode {ip: {SrcIP}, port: {SrcPort}, ipport:{SrcIP+':'+SrcPort} })
  MERGE (dest:IPNode {ip: {DstIP}, port: {DstPort},ipport:{DstIP+':'+DstPort} })
  MERGE (ipcluster)-[has:HAS]->(origin)

  CREATE (flow)-[o:ORIGIN]->(origin)
  CREATE (flow)-[d:DESTINATION]->(dest)
"

t1 <- Sys.time()

tx = newTransaction(graph)

for(i in 1:nrow(cleandata)) {
  row = cleandata[i, ]

  appendCypher(tx, query,
               SrcIP=row$firstSeenSrcIp,
               SrcPort=row$firstSeenSrcPort,
               TimeSeconds=row$TimeSeconds,
               TransportProto=row$ipLayerProtocol,
               DstIP=row$firstSeenDestIp,
               DstPort=row$firstSeenDestPort)
  }
commit(tx)
t2 <- Sys.time()
t2 - t1
summary(graph)
```

> Errors encountered:

```
Error in appendCypher.transaction(tx, query, SrcIP = row$firstSeenSrcIp,  : 
  Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError
Invalid input 'C': expected whitespace, comment, ';' or end of input (line 2, column 74 (offset: 76))
```

Answer (score 0):

My easy bet is the unexpected C is from the second create because there is no ; at the end of the first create constraint.

Comment: Yes I have tried that before and the next error message being prompted is "cannot have multiple statements within a query"

Comment: First thing first, you seem to create the constraints n times. 
What is appendCypher method doing ?

Comment: the appendcypher is trying to retrieve the necessary data such as timeseconds for each data row and create the ipnodes/constraints/relationship on the fly. That's what I have understand to be doing. Do correct me if my understanding is wrong. Thank you.

Comment: ok so your method is doing string replacement.
Display the final queries in your console. Copy paste one in the neo4j browser. Hope the error message will be more useful
Its useless to recreate the constraints for every node. They are created based on labels.
When hope is lost, create a CSV file then load it with LOAD CSV and the command USING PERIODIC COMMIT 5000

Comment: for my project, I am exploring both 2 methods. Its known that the latter method works though.